# tcpdf for Arabic display the characters as question marks '?????? ???'

Tags: php, utf-8, arabic, tcpdf

I wanna create an Arabic pdf as same as the file witch I had in ms Execl format. While creating the pdf using tcpdf in php the Arabic charactors are displyaed as '????' marks.

The characters are copied from my excel file

```
$htmlcontent2 = '<span color="#0000ff">"مجوهرات السليمان"This is Arabic "مجوهرات السليمان" Example With TCPDF.</span>';
```

$pdf->WriteHTML($htmlcontent2, true, 0, true, 0);

the output file display as below,

??? ???? ?????? ??????This is Arabic "??????? ????????"
Example With TCPDF.

Answer (score 14):

I solved this issue by adding the following line:

```
$pdf->SetFont('aealarabiya', '', 18);
```

It turned out that you need to set the proper font type to remove those ugly ????? characters.

The exmaple mentioned in this **[link](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_018.phps)** was very useful to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by following this step:

1. Download TCPDF from here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/tcpdf/
2. Open the TCPDF file after download and go to FONTS
3. Copy these files

   - aealarabiya.ctg.z
   - aealarabiya.z
   - aealarabiya.php
4. Paste in this location: your WHCMS root / **includes/fonts** if fonts folder doesn't exist create it.
5. Go to WHCMS Admin Panel
   Got to WHMCS Set Up / General Setting / Invoice / TCPDF Font Family / custom (aealarabiya)

Answer (score 0):

there might be issue with your character set in your code

here is very good example for official TCPDF to use arabic character to write new pdf.

just go throw [this example](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_018.phps) with your application you can sure solve your issue.

hope this will help to you.

Comment: I have already tried this example but once I open that example file from tcpdf example set the arabic characters display in the editor as 'ØªÙ…Ù‘ÙŽ Ø¨Ù�Ø­Ù…Ø¯ Ø§Ù„Ù„Ù‡ Ø­Ù„Ù‘ Ù…Ø´ÙƒÙ„Ø© Ø§Ù„ÙƒØªØ '

Comment: the example provided in tcpdf contain the arabic letters as latin letters as below,


ØªÙ…Ù‘ÙŽ Ø¨Ù�Ø­Ù…Ø¯ Ø§Ù„Ù„Ù‡ Ø­Ù„Ù‘ Ù…Ø´ÙƒÙ„Ø© Ø§Ù„ÙƒØªØ


Is there any way to create the pdf from the Arabic text that we already have in other ms office files.

Comment: please change your browser character set

Comment: no its not the browser, if I open it in browser from that link that u have given I can see the arabic charactesr properly but if you can download the example and see that the charactoers are changed.  http://sourceforge.net/p/tcpdf/code/ci/master/tree/examples/