# Persian and Arabic strings are not shown in tcpdf

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf

I'm using tcpdf library for generating pdf documents.
But when I want to use Persian (or Arabic) strings, it prints some question marks like `'?'` on the document. How can I handle this issue to print the correct form?
    require_once('tcpdf/tcpdf.php');

```
$irsans = TCPDF_FONTS::addTTFfont('tcpdf/fonts/IRAN-Sans-Bold.ttf', 'TrueTypeUnicode', '', 32);

class CPDF extends TCPDF {

    //Page header
    public function Header() {
                $this->setHeaderFont(Array($irsans, '', 12)); //Set header font
                $this->WriteHTML('سلام', true, 0, true, 0); //TITLE string in persian language
    }
}
// create new PDF document
$pdf = new CPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
```

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 10):

You need to apply settings. I have the same problem with persian words.
I want factor output in Persian.

```
$pdfoutput = 'سلام';

$lg = Array();
$lg['a_meta_charset'] = 'UTF-8';
$lg['a_meta_dir'] = 'rtl';
$lg['a_meta_language'] = 'fa';
$lg['w_page'] = 'page';

require_once 'widgets/photography/libraries/tcpdf/examples/tcpdf_include.php';

// create new PDF document
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

// set document information
$pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
$pdf->SetAuthor('Nicola Asuni');
$pdf->SetTitle('TCPDF Example 001');
$pdf->SetSubject('TCPDF Tutorial');
$pdf->SetKeywords('TCPDF, PDF, example, test, guide');

// set default header data
//$pdf->SetHeaderData(PDF_HEADER_LOGO, PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, PDF_HEADER_TITLE.' 001', PDF_HEADER_STRING, array(0,64,255), array(0,64,128));
$pdf->setFooterData(array(0,64,0), array(0,64,128));

// set header and footer fonts
$pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
$pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));

// set default monospaced font
$pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);

// set margins
//$pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
$pdf->SetMargins(5, 5, 5);
$pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
$pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);

// set auto page breaks
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);

// set image scale factor
$pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);

// set some language-dependent strings (optional)
if (@file_exists(dirname(__FILE__).'tcpdf/examples/lang/far.php')) {

    require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'tcpdf/examples/lang/far.php1');

    // set some language-dependent strings (optional)
    $pdf->setLanguageArray($lg);

    //$pdf->setLanguageArray($l);
}

// set some language-dependent strings (optional)
$pdf->setLanguageArray($lg);

//After Write
$pdf->setRTL(true); 

// set default font subsetting mode
$pdf->setFontSubsetting(true);

// Set font
// dejavusans is a UTF-8 Unicode font, if you only need to
// print standard ASCII chars, you can use core fonts like
// helvetica or times to reduce file size.
$pdf->SetFont('dejavusans', '', 11, '', true);

// Add a page
// This method has several options, check the source code documentation for more information.
$pdf->AddPage();

// set text shadow effect
//$pdf->setTextShadow(array('enabled'=>true, 'depth_w'=>0.2, 'depth_h'=>0.2, 'color'=>array(196,196,196), 'opacity'=>1, 'blend_mode'=>'Normal'));

// Set some content to print

// Print text using writeHTMLCell()
$pdf->writeHTMLCell(0, 0, '', '', $pdfoutput, 0, 1, 0, true, '', true);
// ---------------------------------------------------------

// Close and output PDF document
// This method has several options, check the source code documentation for more information.
$pdf->Output(time(). '.pdf', 'I');
```

Comment: changing the font to "dejavusans", help me.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the font your are using not supported , please check this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17966543/tcpdf-for-arabic-display-the-characters-as-question-marks) also the [official example](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_018.phps).

Answer (score -1):

Refer to https://github.com/ooghry/TCPDF-Persian-Farsi-font
There are a number of Persian fonts in this link, for example btitr,bnazanin ...

Then use below lines in your code:

// convert TTF font to TCPDF format and store it on the fonts folder
$fontname = TCPDF_FONTS::addTTFfont('/path-to-font/FreeSerifItalic.ttf', 'TrueTypeUnicode', '', 96);

// use the font
$pdf->SetFont($fontname, '', 14, '', false);