Problem writing arabic vowels with custom fonts in TCPDF
I tried example No. 18 (https://tcpdf.org/examples/example_018/) and it works very well with the predefined fonts.
However, for my project, I wanted to use the "Traditional Arabic" or "Sakkal Majalla" fonts and i used the tool to convert the TTF font with the following command:
php tcpdf_addfont.php -b -t TrueTypeUnicode -i Traditional-Arabic.ttf

but when I generated the PDF, words containing vowels (الحركات) appear separated instead of being on the word (see attached image).

Do you have any idea how I can resolve this issue?
Thank you in advance.

Traditional-Arabic.ttf might not be compatible with tcpdf. try some from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17966543/tcpdf-for-arabic-display-the-characters-as-question-marks

Most fonts are not compatible unfortunately
